# express-session and connect-mongo setup

Tags: mongodb, express, express-session, connect-mongo

I'm using `express-session` and am now wanting to use `connect-mongo` to persistently store session. I have seen the docs and some tutorials and mostly understand how it works, but I assume you need a mongoDB instance setup in the first place so `connect-mongo` has something to connect to?

Some examples I have seen involve connecting to a test mongoDB on localhost, so is it just a case of installing mongoDB as standard and then using that instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either use a current connection or tell `connect-mongo` to use a new connection.

Using a current connection:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ db: dbInstance })
}));
```

Where `dbInstance` is your current connection.

Using a new connection:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://localhost/test-app' })
}));
```

`url` is just a traditional mongodb connection string.